# How to set [value]="res" <object> in ngAfterViewInit method

Tags: angular8

```html
<mat-select formControlName="adviserNationality">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let res of adviserNationalityRes" [value]="res">
         {{res['nationality']}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

How to set [value]="res"  in ngAfterViewInit method

Answer (score 0):

I could't understand exactly what you are trying to do , but may be this could help you.

**Typescript**

```
     ngAfterViewInit()
            {
             this.FormName.patchValue({     <--- Write your relevant Form Name 
               adviserNationality = "res";
             });    
            }
```

**NOTE**

*When you do this(Above), that option would be selected
But if all options value is same it can cause confusion.So make sure all options value is different*

**HTML**

As you have used   `{{res['nationality']}}`  it looks like your `res` is type array.

There are two possible ways of setting value

Hard Code : `[value] = "res"`

like this

```
<mat-select   class="form-control" formControlName="adviserNationality">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let res of adviserNationalityRes" [value]="res">
         {{res['nationality']}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Dynamic : `[Value] = {{res['Id']}} // I supposed Id exists`

like this

```
<mat-select   class="form-control" formControlName="adviserNationality">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let res of adviserNationalityRes" [value]="{{res['Id']}">
         {{res['nationality']}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: I want to set below object to [value]

Comment: this.nationality = {'active': true, 'addDate': null, 'modDate': null, 'nationality': "Unknown", 'nationalityId': 3};

Comment: Then you should apply an event like OnChange(value) and pass object value to function . In you typescript file you can set it like this this.nationality = value.                                          May be this could help you.